# How to get the topLeft screen position of Visual studio 2008's editor window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-macros

I want to create an addin for vs2008, to show a transparent form/window on the editor of vs2008.

in following code, the "aw.Left" and "aw.Top" is relative value, both is 1.

**QUESTION:**

1. do you know how to get the left/top screen position of the editor part?
2. or I can move the caret to top/left char position, but do you know how to get the screen position of caret?

Great thanks.

```
    public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
    {
        handled = false;
        if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
        {
            if(commandName == "MyAddin1.Connect.MyAddin1")
            {
                Window aw = _app.ActiveWindow;
                int left = aw.Left;
                int top = aw.Top;
```

[image: editor part]

Comment: [`LinkedWindowFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.window.linkedwindowframe.aspx) allegedly gets the parent so you can just go up and up and up until you have the absolute position. Or you could make your overlay a child of the window and avoid needing the absolute position.

Comment: Maybe you can do it with macros

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Win32 `ClientToScreen` function.

Declare the following external function:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
};

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hwndClient, ref POINT lpPoint);
```

You can call this as follows

```
POINT pt = new POINT();
pt.x = left;
pt.y = top;
ClientToScreen(myForm.Handle, ref pt);
```

After this, pt should contain the absolute coordinates of pt. Use `ScreenToClient` for the opposite operation. Using the two, you can also get the location of one point relative to another window (given you know the window handle of both windows).